# convert json to csv using jq bash

Tags: json, jq

have a JSON data like below

```
"metric": {
   "name" : "name1"
},
"values": [
 [
   16590879,
   "0.043984349"
],
"values": [
 [
   16590876,
   "0.043983444"
]
]
```

}
}

writing below jq , but not giving proper result

```
jq -r '[.metric.name,(.values[] | map(.) | @csv)'
```

Actual result

```
[
"name1",
"16590879",\"0.043984349\"",
"16590876",\"0.043983444\"",
"16590874",\"0.043934345\""
```

Expected result

```
name1,16590879,0.043984349
name1,16590876,0.043983444
name2,16590874,0.043934345
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The sample data provided is invalid as JSON, but assuming it has been adjusted as shown below, we would have:

```
< sample.json  jq -r '[.metric.name] + .values[] | @csv'
"name1",16590879,"0.043984349"
"name1",16590876,"0.043983444"
```

If you don't want the quotation marks, then use `join(",")` instead of `@csv`.

---

**sample.json**

```
{
  "metric": {
    "name": "name1"
  },
  "values": [
    [
      16590879,
      "0.043984349"
    ],
    [
      16590876,
      "0.043983444"
    ]
  ]
}
```